# Displaying month in dropdownlist MVC "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to display month and year list to dropdownlist in MVC but i encounter an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

**MODEL**

```
public class AccountingViewModel
    {
    public string StartMonth { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Months
            {
                get
                {
                    return DateTimeFormatInfo
                           .InvariantInfo
                           .MonthNames
                           .Select((monthName, index) => new SelectListItem
                           {
                               Value = (index + 1).ToString(),
                               Text = monthName
                           });
                }
            }
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
    @model TrackAndTrace.ViewModel.AccountingViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("AccountingReport", "Report", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartMonth)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.StartMonth,Model.Years)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartMonth)
    </div>
     }
```

Comment: share your full view code

Comment: @DilipN see updated view code.

Comment: @Reynan Where is `StartYear` property in your model?

Comment: @DilipN sorry it is suppose to be StartMonth,

Comment: @Reynan Where exactly the error occurs?

Comment: @DilipN @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.StartMonth,Model.Months) when i put breakpoint is says null it does not go to Months method

Comment: @Reynan Did you make a mistake again with `Model.Years` not existing in model or is it your issue?

Comment: @DilipN its another mistake i need to display both months and years. same issue. the method is not firing.

Comment: @Reynan : Please check i have solved your problem and let me know

Comment: @Reynan : Have you check with my answer ??

Answer (score 0):

```
This is solution of your problem.

 Replace this code with your code in your AccountingView model.

 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Months
        {
            get
            {
                return DateTimeFormatInfo
                       .InvariantInfo
                       .MonthNames
                       .TakeWhile(monthName => monthName != String.Empty)
                       .Select((monthName, index) => new SelectListItem
                       {
                           Value = (index +     1).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                           Text = string.Format("({0}) {1}", index + 1, monthName)
                       });
            }
        }
```

Replace this code with your view code

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StartMonth, new     SelectList(Model.Months, "Value", "Text", " "))
```

Comment: still the same error. It is null when calling Model.Months

Comment: Please read my updated answer

Comment: same error. i copied your whole code.